# Queues Using Linked List in C only take last node as a whole infinite queue

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, queue, feof

I am working on a data structure project. I am asked to take information from a file called "ToServe.txt". The data in the file is in the form:

```
TicketNumberSpaceStudentIDSpaceStudentName
TicketNumberSpaceStudentIDSpaceStudentName
```

However, implementing the two functions below, I only get the last student infinite times in my queue

```
int Start(advisee** front, advisee** rear) {
  advisee* student, *walker;
  FILE* infp;
  student = (advisee*)malloc(sizeof(advisee));
  infp = fopen("ToServe.txt", "r");
  if(infp == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  while(!feof(infp)) {
    fscanf(infp, "%d", &student->ticket);
    fscanf(infp, "%d", &student->ID);
    fgets(student->name, 100, infp);
    student->next = NULL;
    enqueue(front, rear, student);
  }
  walker = *front;
  fclose(infp);
  return 1;
}
void enqueue(advisee** front, advisee** rear, advisee* ToAdd) {
    if (*front == NULL)
      *front = ToAdd;
    else
      (*rear)->next = ToAdd;
    *rear = ToAdd;
}
```

Comment: `while(!feof(infp)) {` <<-- who taught you that? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/905902

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @wildplasser The while condition is correct, or at least not the problem here. I tried printing the information directly instead of creating a queue and it worked.

Comment: As to the question: you only allocate space for *one* advisee, so why would you expect more than one? They are all the same. It couldn't be any different. You just keep modifying the properties of the same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one item allocated:

```
advisee* student = (advisee*)malloc(sizeof(advisee));
```

...and the loop just keeps mutating that single advisee and repeatedly adds the *same* pointer to the queue. So the queue ends up with pointers to one single advisee.

The solution is to move the allocation inside the loop.